# This tree search function drives me crazy. It return NULL but somehow the value changes in the main function

Tags: c++, tree

My project is composed of 3 files:

tree.h

```
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H

struct nodo{
    char val;
    nodo *left;
    nodo *right;
};

typedef nodo * tree;

bool isNull(tree &t);
void init(tree &t);
bool insert(tree &t, char c);
tree search(tree &t, char elem);
void print(tree &t);

#endif // TREE_H
```

tree.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tree.h"

using namespace std;

static bool isEmpty(tree &t){
    return (t==NULL);
}

bool isNull(tree &t){
    return (t==NULL);
}

void init(tree &t){
    t = NULL;
}

bool insert(tree &t, char c){
    bool res = false;
    if(isEmpty(t)){
        t = new (nothrow) nodo;

        if(t!=NULL){
            t->left = NULL;
            t->right = NULL;
            t->val = c;
            res = true;
        } else {
            res = false;
        }

    } else if(c <= t->val){
        insert(t->left, c);
    } else if(c > t->val){
        insert(t->right, c);
    }
    return res;
}

tree search(tree &t, char elem){
    tree res;

    if(isNull(t)){
        res = NULL;
    } else if(elem== t->val){
        res = t;
    } else if(elem < t->val){
        search(t->left, elem);
    } else if(elem > t->val){
        search(t->right, elem);
    }
    return res;
}



void print(tree &t){
    if(!isNull(t)){
        print(t->left);
        cout << t->val << " ";
        print(t->right);
    }
}
```

and main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tree.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int op;
    char car;
    tree t;
    init(t);
    tree found;

    do{
        cout << "1. Insert" << endl;
        cout << "2. Search" << endl;
        cout << "3. Print" << endl;
        cout << "4. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Choose one-> ";
        cin >> op;

        switch(op){
        case 1:
            cout << "Element to insert: ";
            cin >> car;
            insert(t, car);
        break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Element to look for: ";
            cin >> car;
            found = search(t, car);
            if(!isNull(found)){
                cout << "Found!" << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "Not found" << endl;
            }
        break;

        case 3:
            cout << endl;
            print(t);
            cout << endl;
        break;


        }


    }while(op>=1 && op <=3);

}
```

When I try to search for a value which is not contained in the tree the function return NULL successfully, but in the main function is value changes somehow and it's not NULL anymore. I've been looking into this for hours without any success and the frustration is sky high.

I'd appreciate if you could help me fix the error. Tried debugging aswell without any success.

By the way, tree is an alias for node*

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `search()` sets the value of `res` only if one of the first two `if` conditions are met.

For the remaining two cases, if a recursive call needs to be made, the value of `res` remains unset, and the result of the recursive call gets ignored. An uninitialized pointer to your class gets returned, resulting in undefined behavior.

Therefore, when your `main()` calls `search()`, only the status of the root element with respect to the first two conditions will produce defined behavior.

You should be able to fix this by fixing the last two `if` statements to also set `res` to the return value from the recursive call.